# Unity-2d on Trusty 14.04

Tags: unity, unity-2d

I recently got a laptop for uni work, I had trouble with installation of the normal supported versions of Ubuntu and had to use Trusty 14.04 to get running, my question now is how can I set it to Unity-2d if possible. My laptop gets severe framerate issues with Unity-3d due to low end specs. Any alternative answers are welcome I just want to move onto a low-end shell but Unity-2d is preferrable.

Thanks.

Comment: What trouble did you have installing supported versions? You can set it to Unity-2d when you login; click on the ubuntu logo to the side of your username and choose Unity-2d.

Comment: 2d- is gone since 12.04, and 14.04 is not yet released.

Answer (score 3):

I have a laptop with a graphics card ([gma500](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_GMA#GMA_500)) which has a [framebuffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framebuffer) driver only, resulting in the same horrible framerates/performance.

The best solution for me is running [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/). This is [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) including the same software repository, but with a light weight desktop manager called [LXDE](http://lxde.org/). It is graphically not as slick, but muuuuch faster on light hardware or on systems with some issues. I even recommend it on more modern computers, if you prefer speed above presentation.

If you like the idea, you can give [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) a try by downloading and running it live from a CD or USB-key.

Does this help you?

Answer (score 3):

Starting from Ubuntu 12.10, Unity-2D is no longer in the repository. You should install the Xfce or Lxde desktop environment maybe, or download Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I was getting specific errors whilst trying to install Ubuntu versions below Trusty, it is a known bug and the only work-around known at this moment is using Trusty. I'll see if I can get either of those environments working.