# Ubuntu on chromebook issue (updated ubuntu now facing problem with sudo startunity)

Tags: chromebook, chroot

I updated my Ubuntu on Chromebook. Now I am unable to load it though crouton. As suggested in some posts I tried to update my crouton 'precise'. But still I am facing the same problem. When I use command:

```
sudo startunity
```

it throws an error saying:

```
No chroots with target 'unity' found in /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots
```

Answer (score 0):

Unity2D (required for crouton) is not available in Ubuntu 14.04/trusty. [Is it possible to change Unity 3D to 2D and will I gain any performance boost after that?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487177/is-it-possible-to-change-unity-3d-to-2d-and-will-i-gain-any-performance-boost-af)

Comment: Instead of just providing a link, could you maybe try to give some information? The link might die, over time, and this way your answer will be forever. :D